# python : wait until a function is finished

Tags: python, performance, time, multiprocessing

My script is composed of several functions that execute relatively long bash commands in terms of execution time (retrieve the list of suid binaries, retrieve multiple files, etc).

I have linked these functions to execute them via multiprocessing, as shown below:

```
def main_f():



   queue=Queue()





   proc10= multiprocessing.Process(target=verify_defenses)
   proc2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=useful_software)
   proc3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process)
   proc4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_suid)

   proc6 =multiprocessing.Process(target=path)
   proc7 =multiprocessing.Process(target=writable_directories)
   proc8 =multiprocessing.Process(target=authorized_exec)
   proc9 =multiprocessing.Process(target=crontab)
   proc1 =multiprocessing.Process(target=enum_users)
   proc11 = multiprocessing.Process(target=network_interface)
   proc12 =multiprocessing.Process(target=check_write)
   proc13 = multiprocessing.Process(target=search_files)
      
   
   proc_tab = [proc1, proc2,.... ("speed" tasks)]

   for p in proc_tab:

      p.start()
      


   for p in proc_tab:

         
         

      p.join()

//"slow" tasks
proc4.start()
proc4.join()

proc_x.start()
proc_x.join(), etc
```

my problem is that multiprocessing "executes" the functions too quickly for them to have time to do their job (the function that returns suid returns nothing because of this lack of time for example): what can I do to ask multiprocessing to wait until my function has finished its execution before moving on to the next one?

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of multiprocessing? If you have a specific function that needs to be finished before certain other ones, you can make multiple multiprocessing groups: the ones that don't need that specific function's output, that specific function, then the rest of the ones that do need it's output. Run those three groups sequentially.

Comment: if I understand, I should separate the "fast" functions that I can execute one after the other, and execute separately the slower functions?

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing.

Comment: Either that, or make a callback function which the others will call when they end  and the main one will stay dormant until the others finish

Comment: it is also a possibility indeed:)

Comment: I have edited my code if some people are looking for a similar solution.